# Java connection pool is not limiting the number of TCP connections opened to the DB server

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, connection-pooling

I'm using Hibernate properties to define the connection pool size, along with the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` and `DriverManagerDataSource` to create an `org.hibernate.SessionFactory` and I am observing 1000's of TCP connections being opened to the DB server instead of the upper limit of 100 I would expected with the connection pool size.

The code for setting the connection Hibernate pool looks like this. Note the max size of 100, however I am observing 1000's of connections to the DB server from my workstation - I'm using TCPView on a Windows machine to connect to a MariabDB instance on a Centos OS VM managed by Vagrant (VirtualBox)

```
Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", false);
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.generate_statistics", false);
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.use_sql_comments", false);

hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", 10);
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", 100);
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.c3p0.timeout", 1500);
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements", 5000);
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period", 60);

LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new   LocalSessionFactoryBean();
localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
localSessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
localSessionFactoryBean.setMappingResources("job.persistence.xml");
```

I would expect to see these connections maxing out at 100 and being reused for later executions of loop, but I am observing over 1000 sitting in TIME_WAIT for about a minute before they are closed down. Here is a sample of the output from TCPView:

```
[System Process]    0   TCP localhost   62794   192.168.98.102  3306    TIME_WAIT                                       
[System Process]    0   TCP localhost   62796   192.168.98.102  3306    TIME_WAIT                                       
[System Process]    0   TCP localhost   62797   192.168.98.102  3306    TIME_WAIT                                       
[System Process]    0   TCP localhost   62795   192.168.98.102  3306    TIME_WAIT                                       
[System Process]    0   TCP localhost   62798   192.168.98.102  3306    TIME_WAIT                                       
[System Process]    0   TCP localhost   62801   192.168.98.102  3306    TIME_WAIT
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong but not sure what. I am using Spring to manage the DAO that provides the data access logic. The DAO is registered as a prototype Spring scope while the Singleton `SessionFactory` is injected into the DAO like this:

```
@Bean(name="jobDao")
@Scope(SpringBeanScope.Prototype)
public JobDao jobDao(SessionFactory jobSessionFactory) { //...}
```

Within the DAO, I am calling `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` to access the DB session. The following is an extract from the generic DAO base that demonstrates this:

```
protected Session currentSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

@Transactional
@Override
public void Add(TEntity entity) {

    currentSession().save(entity);
}
```

Does anyone know why so many TCP connections are being opened when the connection pool limit is 100?

**UPDATE**

Since this issue is on a Windows dev machine, I put together a small .NET Console application that uses a parallel for loop to execute a simple SQL select statement to a max thread count of 64, creating a new connection every time:

```
public void Test()
{
    ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
    options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 64;

    Parallel.For(0,
                1000,
                options,
                (i, state) =>
                {
                    ExecuteSql();
                });
}

private void ExecuteSql()
{
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, new SqlConnection(connectionString));

    DataSet orders = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(orders, "Order");

    Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} returned {1} rows", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, orders.Tables[0].Rows.Count);
}
```

The TCPView results look as follows, which is what I would expect to see in a connection pooled solution, i.e. ***TCP connections being reused***

```
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61316   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED 1   88  776 2,684,495       43,800      16      
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61317   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED 1   88  507 1,998,709       6,326       1       
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61318   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED 2   176 862 3,081,722       49,640      19      
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61319   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED 2   176 952 3,128,657       14,600      9       
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61320   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED 2   176 1,149   3,569,440       25,747      8       
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61321   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED 2   176 1,166   3,788,974                       
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61322   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED 2   176 884 3,197,392       8,713       2       
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61323   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED 2   176 535 1,816,150                       
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61324   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED 2   176 631 2,197,973                       
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61327   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED 2   176 1,037   3,344,226       18,980      5       
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61328   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED 3   264 1,271   4,057,097       30,660      13      
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61331   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED 2   176 780 2,639,988       8,760       2       
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61333   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED 2   176 1,041   3,352,777       31,248      12      
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61334   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED 6   995 729 2,387,668                       
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61335   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED 6   995 601 1,917,537       23,937      6       
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61336   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED                                     
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61339   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED                                     
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61340   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED                                     
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61342   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED                                     
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61343   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED                                     
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61344   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED                                     
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61345   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED                                     
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61346   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED                                     
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61356   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED                                     
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61357   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED                                     
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61358   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED                                     
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61359   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED                                                         
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61362   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED                                     
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61363   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED                                     
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61364   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED                                     
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61365   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED                                     
DatabaseTcpPortTester.vshost.exe    5036    TCP localhost   61369   dev-database01  ms-sql-s    ESTABLISHED                                     
[System Process]    0   TCP localhost   61395   dev-database01  epmap   TIME_WAIT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was c3p0 was never being initialised when using a `DriverManagerDataSource` and having hibernate manage the pool by setting the c3p0 properties on the `LocalSessionFactoryBean`

So I switched to a `ComboPooledDataSource` and set the c3p0 properties using the setter methods available here and NOT on the`LocalSessionFactoryBean` so you effectively end up with the following:

```
@Bean(name="dataSource")
public DataSource dataSource() throws PropertyVetoException {

    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", false);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.generate_statistics", false);
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.use_sql_comments", false);

    //note the "hibernate.c3p0...." properties are no longer in use

    ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClass(jobDatabaseProperties.getJobDatabaseDriverClassName());
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl(jobDatabaseProperties.getJobDatabaseUrl());
    dataSource.setUser(jobDatabaseProperties.getJobDatabaseUsername());
    dataSource.setPassword(jobDatabaseProperties.getJobDatabasePassword());

    dataSource.setAcquireIncrement(1);
    dataSource.setMinPoolSize(5);
    dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(100);
    dataSource.setMaxIdleTime(20);

    return new dataSource;
}
```

I can now see c3p0 being initialised in the logs and the number of connections being controlled by the pool as expected.

Hat tip to the "***Have Spring Manage the Pool***" section on http://syntx.io/configuring-c3p0-connection-pooling-with-spring-and-hibernate/

Answer (score 2):

In the netstat output all of them are in `TIME_WAIT` state indicating the state of TCP socket before actually closing. That doesn't mean the DB connection is active it is just that the TCP is in the process of socket closing.

How many of them are in `ESTABLISHED` state? That will tell you the exact number of DB connections opened at that point of time.

You can refer to following link for different TCP socket states. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol

Comment: I thought that was the case, but the problem is with a larger number of items to process across more threads I am exhausting the ports on my machine as its taking over a minute (72 secs on windows) for these ports to be released. Am I missing a hibernate setting to release these ports sooner or is this an OS configuration I need to change?

Comment: Pretty much all of them. There is only 3-4 active (established) at a time on the thread pool of up to 20 threads as we would expect but with 100s and at times 1000s in TIME_WAIT for over a minute I must be doing something wrong, as it looks as though 1 connection is being opened per call to the session.save (or maybe session.getCurrentSession, not sure) which just seems wrong

Comment: IMO, since an OS can support/open 2^16 ports  (theoretically),unless you see some thing above, say a big number like 25000, entries in the TIME_WAIT state we shouldn't worry about those TIME_WAIT state. OS will take of it. Also since you are seeing only 3-4 active connections, some indicators you may want to check are - Thread pool configuration for you web/app server or is GC causing the processing delay or if the java process is craving for memory or resources. You may also want to take some threaddumps and see if your code is waiting too much on synchronization. etc..

Comment: I put together a .NET test application (since I'm on Windows) that runs a simple SELECT statement against a SQL Server DB. I run this in a parallel for loop with a max of 32 threads for 1000 iterations and the results were nothing like from Java. See my latest update to the question

Answer (score 0):

The Hibernate configurations are correct and you should be using C3P0. The only way you'd see more connections than the max pool size is if you are creating the `SessionFactory` for every request.

From your configs, I see that the DAOs are created as prototypes, which is unusual since they should be singletons. Make sure the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` doesn't use a prototype scope as well.

Comment: The factory is singleton and the DAO's are prototype so that the same session isn't shared across threads (this is not a web application). I have tried with singleton DAO's also and had session close errors and observed the same issue with connections in TIMRE_WAIT state, so based on this I'm sure prototype is correct.